# How to run TeamCity service under a user account instead of "System"?

Tags: teamcity

After being unable to clone a private github repo inside a TeamCity command line build step, even when making sure the ssh-agent was running with the correct key, I found this answer:  [Team City Git "Host key verification failed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37971867/team-city-git-host-key-verification-failed?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)
How to do what this answer suggests? How do I run my TeamCity job under a different account than "System"?

Answer (score 2):

If you are running TeamCity agents as a Service on Windows, then go to Server Manager -> Configuration -> Services. Find your TeamCity agent there, right click to see Properties, and go to Log On tab, where you can change default Local System account to anything you want:

[image]

Comment: I'm actually running TeamCity with an EC2 agent pool, which are running Linux.